# Why aren't B.Th., B.Ed., Mus.B., B.Chir. or M.B. degree holders members of Cambridge's Senate?

Tags: united-kingdom

I don't understand the goal or reason behind [B II 2 Degrees | Student Registry](https://www.student-registry.admin.cam.ac.uk/graduation/degrees-under-statute-b-ii-2/b-ii-2-degrees-who-eligible), but I'm even more addled by the boldened sentence below. Why aren't these undergraduate degree-holders members of the Senate? I know medicine (MB,BChir) is an undergraduate degree in the British Isles.

> Holders of Postgraduate Certificates or the **B.Th., B.Ed., Mus.B., B.Chir. or M.B. degrees** are not thereby members of the Senate, so may still be able to receive a degree under Statute B II 2 if they are otherwise eligible and do not hold any Cambridge Masters degree or Doctorate. Holders of the LL.B. degree may become members of the Senate by having it formally re-designated as an LL.M., however, and all holders of the B.A. are entitled to the M.A. once they have held the B.A. for the required period.

Comment: Seems pretty specific to Cambridge.

Answer (score 5):

To some extent, the answer is "because the statutes and ordinances say so". However: these are not 'standard' Cambridge undergraduate degrees. If you go to Cambridge and study a 3-year undergraduate programme in theology, education, music or medicine, you will graduate with a BA degree. The listed degrees are/were awarded for specific, somewhat vocational, courses - for example, the BTh is a [special two-year programme for people training for ordination](https://www.divinity.cam.ac.uk/study-here/ministry).